# How to check for a check box class name on change and add it to an array

Tags: javascript, arrays, if-statement, checkbox, addeventlistener

I am trying to add a certain string "classAtoImage" to an empty array. Here is my code:

```
const tomato = document.getElementById('inputA');
var testArr = [];

tomato.addEventListener('change', (e) => {
    if (e.target.checked || !(tomato.classList.contains('classAtoImage'))) {
        testArr.push('classAtoImage');
        console.log(testArr);
    } else {
        testArr.pop('classAtoImage');
        console.log(testArr);
    }
});
```

But in the output array, it keeps adding the same string every time I click on the checkbox.

Output: `["classAtoImage", "classAtoImage", "classAtoImage"]`

I am expecting to add if the conditions true or remove if it is false.
NOTE: I am listening for a 'change' event on the check box.

Comment: Should your `||` be a `&&` in your if condition? You might even need to rethink your condition. `If (checked) {If (notContains) {add the class}} Else { If (contains) {remove class}}`

Comment: I created a fiddle for the code with a checkbox and if the checkbox has that class it works like expected: https://jsfiddle.net/xkhwjLnb/

Comment: Thanks a lot, friend.

Comment: You're being inconsistent. In the `if` statement, you're checking if the element has the class, down below, you're appending or removing from your custom array.

Comment: @imvain2 If it starts with the class with your fiddle, it works. However, when it doesn't start with the class, it will always print an empty array.

Answer (score 0):

You are having wrong concept around [`push`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/push) and [`pop`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/pop) Array methods, please refer to the documentations.
This will always add a "classAtoImage" string to the array.

```
testArr.push('classAtoImage');
```

What you need to do before `push`ing the value, is to check first if that string exists in the array.

```
if(testArr.indexOf('classAtoImage') !== -1)
    testArr.push('classAtoImage');
```

And to remove it (if it exists), you can `filter` the Array with an arrow function

```
testArr = testArr.filter(s => s !== 'classAtoImage')
```

*Note: this creates a new Array and assigns it to testArr*

Comment: I'm just a newbie :) Thanks for the help.